# MVVM - creating new objects in the viewmodel

Tags: mvvm

Pretend I have a viewmodel in my MVVM application. The ViewModel talks to a service layer, the service layer has a method say SavePerson(person p){..}. doing the Person p = new Person(); in the viewmodel doesn't seem right to me. any suggestion on how to do this in another way..a pattern maybe?

---

Im using relay commands and atm Im creating the new objects inside the command then passing it to PersonService.SavePerson(person) also inside the command. is that bad pratice?

Comment: It depends on where and how you create new Person objects. Is it a user-action?

Answer (score 0):

You should indeed inject the service that is responsible for creating/saving the models (in your case Person) into the view model (interface based of course), then use that one.

If you use a service, you have a more loosely coupled design, but it's just a question on how far you want to go with creating a loosely coupled design.